# How to escape double quotes in below bash script that is being used to send messages on discord using webhook?

Tags: bash, shell, discord, escaping, webhooks

I'm using following script to send messages to discord using webhook:

```
#!/bin/bash
webhookurl="https://discord.com/..."
messagearray=($(curl -s -i https://www.google.com/ | awk 'NR==12'))
message=`echo ${messagearray[@]} | tr -cd "0-9A-Za-z .=_,:\"()-[]{}\\'/'"`;
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"content": "'"$message"'"}' "$webhookurl"
```

The output in terminal is: `alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"`

But in discord it sends without double quotes like this: `alt-svc: h3=:443; ma=2592000,h3-29=:443; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=:443; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=:443; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=:443; ma=2592000,quic=:443; ma=2592000; v=46,43`

I've used `\"` to escape double quotes but this doesn't seems to be working. What's the possible solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not "escape quotes". To handle JSON you use JSON libraries and tools. Like `jq`.

```
message="anything you want here"
data=$(jq -n --arg message "$message" '.content = $message')
curl -d "$data" ...
```

Check your script with shellcheck.